# Quadratic Variation

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Let $$ [X,Y]=\int_{0}^{\tau} (dX_t)(dY_t)$$ where $X_t$ is cadlag process and $Y_t$ is a Brownian motion. Can we say $$ \frac{\partial}{\partial\tau}\int_{0}^{\tau} (dX_t)(dY_t)= 0 $$

Comment: Are you sure you have both $dX_t$ and $dY_t$? Also, if the integral is a continuous process, then sure.

Comment: I made a mistake! Just edited!

Comment: What does $dX_t dY_t$ mean? Did you mean $d[X,Y]_t$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Take $X_t=Y_t=B_t$ to be a Brownian motion started from zero. Then $[X,Y]_t=t$, so in this case $\frac{d}{dt}[X,Y]_t=1$, not zero.